# How to set different resolutions in the android graphical layout

Tags: android

i am a new developer in android applications.
Recently i've been working on creating some UIs.Here comes the problem.

Assume that i need to create an xml file for a UI with a resolution of 500 x 600.
When i create the file,i need to see how it looks like in the graphical layout window in eclipse from time to time.But i got only 3.7in WVGA or 4.0in QVGA or others,while no 500x600 resolutions.

So how can i be able to see this UI in the graphical layout window with the specified resolution?
I've been searching it for some days,yet i don't make it.

Any help will be appreaciate.
thanks a lot!
^_^

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if that was dynamic but if its really needed you can create [version for each resolution](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).

Comment: in order to make my app looks good on every certain device,i guess i need to create versions for each resilution.and i've known how to make it,thanks guys~~~

Answer (score 0):

Just open the list with the available configurations and click the "Custom..." entry.

A new window pops up. Scroll down and click on the "Custom" entry, then click the "New..." button, and you are able to create a customized "device" with your resolution.

Comment: You should flag the question answered if you got the answer.